# If a table is horizontally partitioned can it be queried by primary key?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a table that looks like this

```
CREATE TABLE mytable 
(
    id int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    customer_id [int] NOT NULL,
    blessdate date NOT NULL,
    value1 varchar(max) NULL,
    value2 varchar(max) NULL

    CONSTRAINT [PK_History] 
       PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([id] ASC)
          WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, 
                IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

This table will be horizontally partitioned by hashing the `customer_id` across several computers. Can I query this partitioned table like this?

```
select * 
from mytable 
where id = 6709
```

As you can see I did not include the `customer_id` in the query. If I query the table like this will there be a performance penalty? How will SQL Server know what partition to query?

Comment: My guess would be yes... you'll have to index scan each partition individually to find the right customer_id.  The optimizer doesn't have any hints as to which PK is on which partition, because the partition is on a different column.

Comment: It would check all the partitions, but of course you can run the query.  It wouldn't need to do a scan, because it can find the data quickly in the index.

Comment: "This table will be horizontally partitioned by hashing the customer_id across several computers" how are you going to do that then? Without an explanation of exactly the scheme you have in mind this question is not answerable.

Answer (score 0):

Every partition will need to be touched when the partitioning column is not specified in the `WHERE` clause predicate.  If a suitable index exists, a seek against each partition can be performed rather than a scan.  The additional overhead depends on the number of partitions and depth of the b-tree index.  With a singleton lookup, the performance will be worse compared to a non-partitioned table.

Note, however, that SQL Server requires the partitioning column be part of all unique indexes, including the primary key.  Consequently, if you partition on a hash value, the hash will need to be part of the primary key if the primary key is partitined.  To implement a primary key constraint on `id` alone, the PK index must not be partitioned.

You mentioned that customer_id will be hashed across several computers. Are you saying you plan to partition the table across multiple servers?

Comment: Yes, I am planning to partition the table across multiple servers.

Comment: How are you planning to access the table across multiple servers?  A UNION ALL view using linked servers?

Answer (score 0):

Your queries will still make use of a clustered index scan when this field is used. This index will most likely live in the PRIMARY file group since the index is not partitioned. You will not be able to use it in partition specific functions as it is not on the partitioned file group. However, it will behave like regular index.

One thing to note is that more than likely your primary data file will contain the entirety of the index and if it get really large your backups backups and what not will take longer over time.